# How does one build a facebook app as a Company user (rather than a personal app)?

Tags: facebook-apps

I'm building a Facebook app for a client who have a Facebook company page and I'm stumped as to how to develop the app so that they can actually have access to it without binding it with my own personal FB Login (to which I obviously have no desire to grant them access).

They have added me as an admin to their FB page but when I'm logged into that and go to developer.facebook.com I'm told that to proceed I have to switch back to my own personal account.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here, but am totally confused as to what the process is to build an app for a third party, so that they don't have to give me their personal FB login and I don't have to give them my own.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the **Roles** settings of the FB app to add Admins (and optionally Developers, Testers, and Insight Users). Each app can have multiple admins.  When you create the app you'll be an admin, of course. Then, go to the **Roles** tab in your app's settings and add others as admins (note, you must be FB friends with them). The people you have added must then visit the Developers site, accept the admin request (under **Apps**), and will then have admin privileges.

Another way is create a FB group whose members are admins of the app. This is done the same way, but instead of typing a person's name, click "Create a group for administrators" in the "Add Administrators" dialog. Then, add people to the group.

In fact, any of your existing FB groups can be added as an admin, developer, tester, or insight user of the app.

Yet another option is to have the client create the FB app initially (ie. just the minimum config), and then add you as an admin.

More on Roles:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

Comment: awesome! thanks. I knew I must be missing something obvious. And hey! Welcome to Stack!.

Answer (score 2):

You should create and manage Facebook apps using your real, personal accounts.

You can add multiple, real users to be administrators of an app, and you can add them under several different "roles". You should never give another person the username and password to login to your personal Facebook account.

You should not setup a new Facebook user in order to manage apps. When Facebook's automated systems detect a non-real user account, and that account is suspended, all apps that account is connected with will also be affected.

If you want an easy way to control many users having access to many apps, you can create a secret Facebook group - add all the users who you want to admin the app to the group, then in the Facebook app dashboard, you can add that group to one of the app's role groups. This method has the advantage that, if someone joins or leaves the company, you just have to add/remove them from this group, and they'll then be able to edit (or not) all the apps to which that group has been added.

In short - always use your real accounts - there are ways to make it work for people like you building apps for clients.

Comment: I faced this. I created an account just to create an app because I didn't want to use my personal account. The new account was disabled through Facebook's automated systems without any chance of recovery, and I lost my app and all the hard work I put in. Sad face.